# Opencart 2.1.x RoundUp Issue in Cart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.1.x and facing issue in price calculations.

Below is the scenario that i am currently on

```
Product Price: 503 (without VAT)
Special Price: 428 (15% Off) [Without VAT]
```

While Showing prices in store, VAT(5%) is added automatically as expected

```
Product Price: 525 (with VAT) (actual value: 528.15)
Special Price: 449 (15% Off) [With VAT] (actual value: 449.4)
```

**Till here everything works well** (upto Product Detail Page)

> Issue comes up when product is added to Cart and quantity is changed in Cart.

- In cart `product rate` is shown as `449` and when it is multiplied by 2 then cost shall come as **`898`** but right now it is showing up as **`899`** because
- Subtotal and Total are also shown as `449`, which is wrong

> Multiplication  is done as **(449.4*2)** NOT **(449*2)**

Is there any solution to resolve this?

I thought of rounding up the Tax Calculation in Cart as below

```
$this->currency->format(round($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], 
$product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))));
```

But in this way i have to change many files? Is there any easy wayout for this?

Comment: @shadyyx .. Need your advice here

Comment: @Rupak Nepali .. Can you also please advice here